# Is there any other way to write the following code

Tags: apex

I have a code like this -

```
//there i get all the Jaipur city employee list
List<Employee> employeeList = [select ID from Employee where city='Jaipur'];
```

Now i need to get Departments of these Employees. I do like -

```
List<ID> idsList = new List<ID>();

//Iterate employeeList to get employee IDS 
for(Employee emp : employeeList){
    idsList.add(emp.id);
}

// Then get Department List of these ids
List<Department> departmentList = [select ID, name from Department where empId IN: idsList];
```

I need to ask Is there any other way to get Departments? i mean i don't want to iterate over employeeList to form idsList and then use those ids in next query to get departmentList.

can't i get IDS list directly from employeeList without iterating it completely?

Comment: You could do Set<Id> idsList = new Map<Id,Employee>( [Select ...] ).keySet(); or I *think* you can even just use employeeList in place of :idsList in your query but you'd have to try that

Comment: will new Map<Id,Employee>( [Select ...] ).keySet(); throw any exception if  [Select ...] returns 0 results ?

Comment: No, it will just be an empty set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think u can use map instead of list like below

```
Map<id,Employee>  EmpMap = new Map<id,Employee>([select ID from Employee where city='Jaipur']);
```

and use this one in second query like

```
List<Department> departmentList = [select ID, name from Department where empId IN:EmpMap.keySet()];
```

Check below link for more details

http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/initialising-maps-from-queries

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Department> departmentList = [select ID, name from Department where empId IN (select ID from Employee where city='Jaipur')];
```

Here is other way of doing the same without iteration.

Comment: Yes i can do like this as well but i would not be able to use this ID list in following code if i go for it. Even you deserve 1 vote up

Comment: If you want to use this ID in other places then aggregation through map query as Venkatesh mentioned is nice approach.Thanks

Comment: Yes you are right mohith